# Create a column of bools from a pandas DataFrame where True indicates existence of a string in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I've using Pandas for data analysis (and teaching myself Pandas) over the past three months or so now.

I have a Pandas DataFrame like the one below:

`df`

```
client_id    opp_id    opportunity_status
4312         80465     Closed Won
4312         34508     Closed Won
4312         56478     Pending
3456         29930     Closed Lost
3456         70331     Pending
3456         65203     Closed Won
5203         29930     Closed Lost
5203         70331     Pending
5203         65203     Closed Lost
5203         65203     Closed Lost
```

I want to efficiently create this second DataFrame:

`has_cw`

```
client_id    has_closed_won_opp
4312         True
3456         True
5203         False
```

Where `has_cw.client_id` is the unique values from `df.client_id` and `has_cw.has_closed_won_opp` is a list of bools where `True` indicates that there is at least one "Closed Won" opportunity in `df`.

I'm having trouble thinking of a good way of doing this, other than inefficiently looping through `df` in this manner:

```
has_cw = dict()
for id in df.client_id.unique():
    has_cw_bool = 'Closed Won' is in list(df[df['client_id'] == id]['opportunity_status'])
    has_cw[id] = has_cw_bool
```

And then turning the `has_cw` dict into a DataFrame.

How can I do this efficiently? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby.agg`, for each *client_id* check if any of the *opportunity_status* is equal to *Closed Won*:

```
df.groupby('client_id', as_index=False).opportunity_status.agg(lambda x: x.eq('Closed Won').any())

# client_id   opportunity_status
#0     3456                 True
#1     4312                 True
#2     5203                False
```

---

Or a faster version:

```
df.opportunity_status.eq('Closed Won').groupby(df.client_id).any().reset_index()

#   client_id   opportunity_status
#0       3456                True
#1       4312                True
#2       5203               False
```

---

```
%timeit df.groupby('client_id', as_index=False).opportunity_status.agg(lambda x: x.eq('Closed Won').any())
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.84 ms per loop

%timeit df.opportunity_status.eq('Closed Won').groupby(df.client_id).any().reset_index()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 2.06 ms per loop
```

Comment: I like the faster version.  I need to train myself to think this way first. +1

Comment: @Psidom Great solution, I figured that there was probably a one-liner. Thanks!